# Lib/Class which can execute Methods written as Strings

Tags: java

For example `Awesome.run("System."+"exit();");`
Is there any class or lib which I could use for something like this?
It would be very helpful...

Comment: Assuming you don't only need to run something like the above, you can use reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) documentation and tutorials. Basically, it helps to execute programming statements at `Runtime`.